# How do you use change streams to watch a document with a specific document ID in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I cannot figure out how to watch a specific document's changes in MongoDB. Basically, I am using Socket IO to attach a change stream to that user's document.

Here is my code currently. The issue is that it is returning other documents when any document changes. I've also tried it with "fullDocument._id" instead of "documentKey._id".

```
    const filter = {
        $match: {
            'documentKey._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(socket.decoded_token.id)
        }
    }
    const options = { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' }
    const changeStream = User.watch(filter, options)
    changeStream.on('change', (change) => {
        console.log(change)
    })
```

Thank you

Comment: `collection.watch` expects an array as its first argument.  Do you get different results if you make `filter` an array instead of an object?

Comment: @Joe Hey this was indeed the issue. I ended up wrapping the filter in an array and it works golden. Thank you so much! I was stuck on this for way longer than I should have been.

Comment: Happy to help.  I propose we close this question as a simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
col := mongodb.Collection("users")
change, err := col.Watch(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{},
    options.ChangeStream().SetFullDocument(options.UpdateLookup))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
defer change.Close(ctx)
for change.Next(ctx) {
    log.Println(string(change.Current))
    // there will be "fullDocument" included
    // ... your logic
}
```